# How to uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from Windows 8 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot

My system is running Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I would like to Uninstall both versions of Ubuntu and then freshly install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I don't have any windows recovery disks or Installation Media.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you installed the other Ubuntu: you install 14.04 by inserting the 14.04 installation media and at the partitioning related part of the installation you delete the Ubuntu partitions, remake a partition lay-out for 14.04 and finish the installation.